# How to divide an interval on 10 equal intervals?

Tags: plotting, intervals

I have a simple function f(x)= t [0.216019, 0.216971]. How do I tell the software to divide this interval into 10 equal intervals (and also to give me their values)?

Comment: Have you seen the function `Subdivide`?

Comment: This question makes no sense:  `t [0.216019, 0.21691]` makes no sense in the *Mathematica* computer language, the topic of this site.

Comment: Look at [`Subdivide`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) in the documentation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How would you write an interval in Mathematica language if you had measured time from 0.216019 seconds to 0.216971 seconds? Just looking for help, total beginner here :)

Comment: What do you mean by "write an interval"?  Tell me how you would do it in *any* other language, and then I'll tell you how to do it in *Mathematica*.  I have a feeling this won't help you at all, but this is how you specify a time range:  `DayRange[DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], 
 DateObject[{2014, 1, 31}], "BusinessDay"]`.

Comment: Look at [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html), too.

Comment: `Subdivide[0.216019, 0.216971, 10]` gives you a list of points that equally divide the first two numbers into 10 equal intervals, but I sense this will be of no help to you either.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  You're right! Subdivide command will definitely do. :)

Comment: @continuity But making a list of equally separated points given the smallest and largest is absolute trivial.  Is this *really* what you were asking?!

Answer (score 1):

You make us guess what you're trying to achieve. Given that you used the *plotting* tag, perhaps you're attempting to plot some samples of your function. Taking the interval as 0 to 3, and the function as Sin, here's the one way:

```
abcissas = Subdivide[0, 3.0, 10]
ordinates = Sin /@ abcissas
ListPlot[Transpose[{abcissas, ordinates}]]
```

Or, in more idiomatic code:

```
ListPlot[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Subdivide[0, 3.0, 10]]
```

Comment: I'm trying to plot gaussian division for my physics experiment. Given instructions by my professor, I was told to 1. divide my given interval of measurement (time- min, max (look up)) to 10 equal intervals, 2. then calculate the probability of measurements falling into each interval, 3. then plot gaussian division for given data (in the same graph). I had already had problems with 1.step. If you can give me some recommendations, I would be really grateful.

Comment: This is a problem reasonably solvable with a pencil (or with *Mathematica*, if you've mastered it). We try not to do people's homework for them.

Comment: Yes! Solved it! Pencil and Paper work wonders :)